# Eventarc Triggers Not Receiving Events When GKE clusters are created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I want to create an eventarc trigger which can send payload messages to Cloud Run whenever a new GKE cluster is created.The code seems to be working when I created another eventarc trigger which send messages to Cloud Run whenever a compute engine VM is created. is there any configuration that I am missing as I see only below options while configuring the eventarc for GKE. Please help.
google.cloud.gkeconnect.v1.EgressService.Egress
google.cloud.gkeconnect.v1beta1.EgressService.Egress